# POS doesn't start printing

Tags: android, printing, outputstream, printwriter

I am building an Android Application that helps users to print a receipt. What I've done so far:

Right now, I can find the device/printer(DATECS DP-25) through Bluetooth and connect it to the printer. The connection flow works perfectly. Problem is that my printer doesn't start printing at all with the commands that I've introduced so far.

Probably commands are wrong, or I don't really know exactly what is the problem. I tried a lot of apps but none of them with success in printing. Just one app from PlayStore it's working but no access to the code of that app.

Code for the printing flow:

Initializing variables:

```
private suspend fun init(): Boolean {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        return@withContext try {
            uuidSting = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
            bluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuidSting)
            bluetoothSocket.connect()
            outputStream = bluetoothSocket.outputStream
            inputStream = bluetoothSocket.inputStream
            printWriter = PrintWriter(outputStream.bufferedWriter(Charsets.ISO_8859_1))
            true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e.stackTraceToString())
            false
        }
    }
}
```

Print function:

```
fun print(text: String){
    printerController.apply {
        initPrinter()
        patchText(text)
        nextLine()
        nextLine()
    }
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
    fun initPrinter() {
        printWriter.write(0x1B)
        printWriter.write(0x40)
        printWriter.flush()
    }

@Throws(IOException::class)
    fun patchText(text: String) {
        printWriter.println(text)
        printWriter.flush()
    }

@Throws(IOException::class)
    fun nextLine() {
        printWriter.write("\n")
        printWriter.flush()
    }
```

I would be more than happy if anybody can help me with some advice or directions.

Comment: Try writing something on output stream like `outputStream.write("hi".getBytes());`. I have not used PrintWriter but writing in outputstream directly worked for me

Comment: I've used this method with outputStream, still not working.

Comment: Can you try `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` instead of `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord`

Comment: Still nothing ... Are there chances of problems at the thermal printer?

Comment: Take a test print in thermal printer to check if it is working fine. Also you need to send "\n" at the end of content. And this is my working [code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/svvyKN56PT/)